# cannot get $i <= 10 into session

Tags: php, while-loop

Hello i have a while loop inside a select box that loops to 10, and allows you to select one of the outputted options and when you go to submit it will put this into a section to be used again later but i cannot get it to work, the idea is to select an item, and then select the quantity i have a price script working with the item part but i cannot get the quantity to carry over in a session (tested by echo'ing the session) heres the loop

```
echo '<select class="color" name="tickquant"><option></option>';
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 10) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        $i++;
    }
echo '</select>';
```

I am using this to get the session

```
$tickquant = $_POST['i'];
$_SESSION['tickquant'] = $tickquant;
```

If anyone can see the problem with this can you give me an indication of where i am going wrong, after the session is made it uses a header redirect to a page that calls it and echo's it, but it doesnt echo so i know it's not getting through

Comment: The name of your select field is `tickquant`, not `i`. Enable error reporting to see notices

Comment: also make sure you have session_start() on top of both the files..

Comment: @OneTrickPony THANK YOU i spent ages on this been working on this shopping cart since 6am (18 hours now....) i think i just need sleep i have this on ever page

error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Sadly it doesnt work for all errors the university has disabled error reporting the above used to work but it hasnt been working recently. but thanks for that, spent an hour, always the small things :'( right im going to bed......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `for` loop

```
echo '<select class="color" name="tickquant"><option></option>';

     for($i=1; $i <=10; $i++){
        echo "<option value='$i'> $i </option>";
      }

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tickquant = $_POST['tickquant']; //this is the change
$_SESSION['tickquant'] = $tickquant;
```